# Custom class cannot be cast

Tags: java, inheritance, casting

I created 2 classes in this code example: Monster and Zombie. Monster is a superclass and  Zombie is a child class of Monster.

This is my code:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Monster monster = new Monster();
        monster = (Zombie) monster;

    }
}
```

This is the `Monster` class:

```
public class Monster {

}
```

And here is the other class called `Zombie` that extends `Monster`:

```
public class Zombie extends Monster {

}
```

When I run the main method, I get the following error:

```
class Monster cannot be cast to class Zombie (Monster and Zombie are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
```

I only get the error in runtime. For context: I was following [this tutorial](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/referencing-subclass-objects-subclass-vs-superclass-reference/).

Comment: Zombie is Monster but not every Monster is Zombie... Especially not specialised Monster

Comment: @Selvin -- so should I cast the other way around?

Comment: It's oop's basics... You can only downcast if in variable of base type is in fact stored reference to upper class. Please read the link that's you post in the question carefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it means you cannot turn the monster into a Zombie. Since Zombie is an extension of Monster, you would you something like this:

```
Monster monster = new Zombie();
```

does it work now?